# ASP.NET Core 6: Windows Authentication doesn't work in docker linux host

Tags: asp.net, docker, kerberos

Environment:

- Intranet
- Domain (Active Directory 2012)

I'm trying to create an ASP.NET Core 6 application to run in a Docker (Linux) container with Windows authentication, and the goal is get the currently logged in Windows user in the domain.

I've followed [these instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/windowsauth?view=aspnetcore-8.0&tabs=visual-studio).

I've create a simple asp.net with the basic template that use Windows authentication

This is the main part:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

    // Add services to the container.
    builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
    builder.Services.AddAuthentication(NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                    .AddNegotiate(options =>{});

    builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
    {
        // By default, all incoming requests will be authorized according to the default policy.
        options.FallbackPolicy = options.DefaultPolicy;
    });

    builder.Services.AddRazorPages();

    var app = builder.Build();

    // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    }
    app.UseStaticFiles();

    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "default",
        pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

    app.Run();
}
```

On the domain controller, I've added a service SPNs with:

```
setspn -A HTTP/my-app.my-domain.local ACCOUNT_NAME
setspn -A HTTP/my-app@MY-DOMAIN.COM ACCOUNT_NAME
```

Then generate a keytab file with:

```
ktpass -princ HTTP/my-app.my-domain.local@MY-DOMAIN.LOCAL 
       -mapuser my-domain\user-name -pass my-password 
       -crypto AES256-SHA1 -ptype KRB5_NT_PRINCIPAL 
       -out c:\temp\krb5.keytab
```

Then I've created the `krb5.conf` file with this:

```
[appdefaults]
    default_lifetime      = 25hrs
    krb4_convert          = false
    krb4_convert_524      = false

    ksu = {
        forwardable       = false
    }

    pam = {
        minimum_uid       = 100
        forwardable       = true
    }

    pam-afs-session = {
        minimum_uid       = 100
    }

[libdefaults]
    default_realm         = JUSCHUBUT.LOCAL

[realms]
     MY-DOMAIN.LOCAL = {
        kdc            = RWDC4.MY-DOMAIN.LOCAL
        default_domain = MY-DOMAIN.LOCAL
    }
    MY-APP.MY-DOMAIN.LOCAL = {
        kdc            = RWDC4.MY-DOMAIN.LOCAL
        default_domain = MY-DOMAIN.LOCAL
    }

[domain_realm]
    my-domain.local.    = MY-DOMAIN.LOCAL
    .my-domain.local.    = MY-DOMAIN.LOCAL
    my-app.my-domain.local.    = JMY-DOMAIN.LOCAL
    .my-app.my-domain.local.    = MY-DOMAIN.LOCAL

[logging]
default      = CONSOLE
default      = SYSLOG:INFO
default = FILE:/var/log/krb5-default.log
kdc = CONSOLE
kdc = SYSLOG:INFO:DAEMON
kdc = FILE:/var/log/krb5-kdc.log
admin_server = SYSLOG:INFO
admin_server = DEVICE=/dev/tty04
admin_server = FILE:/var/log/krb5-kadmin.log
```

When I create the image, I copy the files `krb5.keytab` and `krb5.conf` into `/etc/`.

When I try to run my app I get the following error:

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
> GssApiException: GSSAPI operation failed with error - An unsupported mechanism was requested.
>
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Negotiate.NegotiateHandler.HandleRequestAsync()
>
> Stack Query Cookies Headers Routing
> GssApiException: GSSAPI operation failed with error - An unsupported mechanism was requested.
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Negotiate.NegotiateHandler.HandleRequestAsync()
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Negotiate.NegotiateHandler.HandleRequestAsync()
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uM3ev.png)

When I try to run my app I get the following error:

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
> GssApiException: GSSAPI operation failed with error - An unsupported mechanism was requested.
>
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Negotiate.NegotiateHandler.HandleRequestAsync()
>
> Stack Query Cookies Headers Routing
> GssApiException: GSSAPI operation failed with error - An unsupported mechanism was requested.
>
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Negotiate.NegotiateHandler.HandleRequestAsync()
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Negotiate.NegotiateHandler.HandleRequestAsync()
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)

The expected result is to be able to get the current Windows user.

Comment: Did you follow those instructions closely? I don't know if it helps, but they say you also need `options.EnableLdap(...)` but I can't see this in yours

Comment: I've follow the "Linux and macOS environment configuration" environment

Comment: Hi!, Now I realize that these instructions work, but only with Edge. When I try to access with Firefox or Chrome, I get the above error. It seems that it is the way these browsers handle kerberos